# IllegalFormatCoversionException - Error al concatenar variable formateada con sting

Tags: java

Al concatenar variable (formateada: "%.1f %n") y `String`, devuelve el siguiente error. Si lo imprimo en dos `System.out.print` diferentes, hace un salto de linea. ¿Cómo se debe hacer?

Error:

> Nota final = Exception in thread "main"
>   java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.String

Al compilar no da error, pero al ejecutar sí.

Código:

```
double sumaNotaFinal = 7535674; 
System.out.printf("%.1f %n", sumaNotaFinal + " /10 ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes dos problemas

- Primeramente el valor la cadena debes ser sustituido en `%s` que representa un carácter tipo `String` y no debes usar `%n`.
- no debes concatenar el valor `String` (`" /10 "`), debes definirlo como valor a sustituir (usa `,` en lugar de `+` ).

---

```
 double sumaNotaFinal = 7535674;
 //System.out.printf("%.1f %n", sumaNotaFinal + " /10 ");
 System.out.printf("%.1f %s", sumaNotaFinal , " /10 ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Hechale un vistazo a [éste link](http://puntocomnoesunlenguaje.blogspot.com/2012/08/java-printf.html) ya que si usas en este caso `1f` haces referencia a un número real:

[image: tabla de caracteres de conversión]

en todo caso no deberias concatenar simplemente realizarlo con el **double**:

```
System.out.printf("%.1f %n", sumaNotaFinal);
```